# submit button freeze different behaviour of chrome, safari and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to update the submit button on click. the text change from "submit" to "Please wait..." its working fine on chrome, safari and firefox. After loading the result page and press the back button to come back to the form the submit button still with the text "Please wait". this only happen with firefox and safari. with chrome it'w working fine.

This is the javascript code

```
function checkloadingForm(form) //
{
  form.myButton.disabled = true;
  form.myButton.value = "Please wait...";
  return true;
}
```

in the html form I have added the following in the form tag:

```
onsubmit= "return checkloadingForm(this);
```

what is wrong and what can I do to ensure same behaviour between the different browser?
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think it's because recent pages are stored in a cache, and won't be downloaded again from the server, if the page accessed by the back button

Comment: You could add another function that triggers on 'pageshow' which sets the button up again.  `$(window).on('pageshow', function(){ resetMyButton(); });`